# MacOs-pipeline fails with specific image version

Tags: macos, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline using a macos-latest image. That constantly fails when the image version is 20201212.1. And it works as expected with the image version 20210110.1.

Is there a way to select the image version in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [**Microsoft-hosted agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run pipelines, typically it will automatically update the image to the latest release for use (generally updated weekly). And we can't specify the image version of the agents.

Currently the released latest image version of macOS agent (**`macOS X Catalina 10.15`**) is **`20201212.1`** (see [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments#available-environments)).

The image version **`20210110.1`** is **Pre-release** now (see [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/releases/tag/macOS-10.15%2F20210110.1)). Currently, this image version has not been deployed completely on Azure DevOps, and there may be few regions are be able to use this image version.

In your case,

> That constantly fails when the image version is 20201212.1. And it works as expected with the image version 20210110.1.

What is the details of the error message in the output logs?

If the issue is caused by different versions of some software installed on the image, you can try to update or install the software with the versions you require. to view more details, you can reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-can-i-manually-select-versions-of-tools-on-the-hosted-macos-agent).

If the issue still exists after changing the software versions, I recommend that you can open an issue on the "[**actions/virtual-environments**](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/new/choose)" repository for more help.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I'm quite new to Azure DevOps and do not know the specifics about different image-releases and such. The error happens nearly always at the same time but I only get an unspecific bash error during compiling a go-library. Feels like a kind of a timeout.
If there is no way to opt-in for the pre-release, then I think I have to wait until the new image gets rolled-out everywhere.